# No any plot with networkD3 in R

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript, networkd3

I tried to run this simple rscript on both RStudio and R x64 but nothing appeared as a result. No plot, nothing... Could someone help please?

```
# Load package
library(networkD3)

# Create fake data
src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A",
    "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J",
        "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
networkData <- data.frame(src, target)

# Plot
simpleNetwork(networkData)
```

Code taken by: http://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/

---

I appreciate all your answers! I found a solution that worked to me.
Using the command:

```
%>% saveNetwork(file = 'File.html')
```

save an .html file and open it via browser.

Comment: It does show in in `Viewer` tab on mine latest Rstudio and R for Mac. Have you tried updating things?

Comment: What version of R? what OS? What version of the package do you have? This info can be found by calling `sessionInfo()` in R. Are you running this with `rscript`? or is that a random tag? (that's for running R scripts from the command line)

Comment: It does work for me with RStudio Version 0.99.1281 and R version 3.3.1 Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200).